# Avoid fetching @ManyToOne property in Spring data JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have three entities as below. I'm using Lombok based getters and setters:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, exclude = { "cClasses"})
class AClass {
   // some properties
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aClass", orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<CClass> cClasses;
}

class BClass {
  // some properties
}

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, exclude = { "aClass", "bClass"})
class CClass {
  // other properties
  // this is bidirectional
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "A_ID")
  private AClass aClass;

  // this is unidirectional
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", referencedColumnName = "B_ID")
  private BClass bClass;
}
```

And by JPA repository class looks like as below:

```
@Repository
public interface CClassRepository extends JpaRepository<CClass, Long> {
  List<CClass> findByBClassBidIn(List<Long> ids);
}
```

The output is coming as expected but the performance is very poor. I can see in logs that select queries for all AClass is also getting executed. How can I avoid the calls to @ManyToOne property aClass.

I tried using @JsonManagedReference and @JsonIgnore on aClass property of CClass. But still it is fetching those records when I'm calling repository method. Please suggest how to solve this problem.

Comment: Putting JsonIgnore on aClass properties won't prevent Jackson to serialize properties of CClass. It's on the CClass properties that you need to put this annotation.

Comment: @JBNizet I mean ```@JsonIgnore``` on aClass property of CClass. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to invert the relationship, so `ClassB` can know about `ClassC`

```
class BClass {
  @OneTOMany(...)
  private CClass cClass;
}

@Repository
public interface BClassRepository extends JpaRepository<BClass, Long> {

  @Query("select ClassB.cClass where ClassB.id is in `ids`") // might be wrong syntax
  List<CClass> findCclassesByBClassIdIn(List<Long> ids);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It only queries database once i.e from the owner side which is the one with @JoinColumn annotation.